# xrandr fails to change screen resolution on Arch Linux

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, arch-linux, xrandr

I have a dual-monitor setup in my notebook, which is running Arch Linux with Gnome 3 as Desktop Environment.

My graphic card is Intel HD Graphics 3000 and my external monitor (VGA1) is a Philips 202EL, which best resolution is 1600x900.

I've tried to run the following commands:

```
$ cvt 1600 900
$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1600x900_60.00
$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1600x900_60.00
```

As result, the external monitor screen blinks, but the resolution is not changed. I've tried to run with `gtf` instead of `cvt` as well, but with no luck.

Is there something I am missing? Is there any alternative way to fix my monitor screen resolution?

Comment: Why are you not executing `xrandr` using `sudo`? A very good tutorial is [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/).

Comment: Any answer to my comment? Felipe Arenales? Shinra tensei?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly edit the xorg.conf after you generate one. Take a look at this thread: http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?id=14

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `xrandr` calls are not effective since you are not running
them as elevated root.

You should run the calls as:

```
sudo xrandr ...
```

A very detailed tutorial with screenshots on using `xrandr` can be found
in the Ubuntu Handbook article:
[How to Set A Custom Screen Resolution in Ubuntu Desktop](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/).

Comment: Comment by Shinra tensei: I am sorry for having to comment like this, as you can see my reputation points dropped to 1 because of the bounty and I'm simply unable to comment at all. My answer is no, this does not work. I have to say it worked with and without sudo before the day this started to fail, and it still works now, it's just that now the resolution doesn't stay as set with xrandr, but instead it reverts after a very short amount of time. But the command worked and still works, and it doesn't throw a permission denied message or anything without sudo, so using it is not the solution.

Comment: @Shinratensei: Do you have installed any automatic display setting product such as [redshift](https://github.com/jonls/redshift) or Ubuntu's 'Night light' feature?